# Couldn't find any page with the nodeId = 1245. This is most likely caused by the page isn't published! Parameter name: nodeId

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

I am using a local installation of Umbraco 4.7 and I downloaded "Blog for Umbraco" from http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/ and installed it in my Umbraco installation.

In the content tree I navigate to the Blog folder, right click and I create a new Blog post. After creating this I save and publish it, but it gives the following error:

***Couldn't find any page with the nodeId = 1245. This is most likely caused by the page isn't published!
Parameter name: nodeId***

I checked and the node 1245 does not appear in the **App_Data\Umbraco.config** but it appears in the DB in the **cmsContentXml** table.

Any idea how to solve this?

I read that I could build the DLLs again but I do not have the expertise to do it.

Comment: What happens if you create a post from the editor exposed by the root "Content" node? It could be problematic you just adding them directly under "Blog" since B4U will want to auto-create `DateFolder`s. Also, did you ask this over on [Umbraco's forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/)?

Comment: If I create the post from the editor exposed by the root "Content" node I have the same problem. I just asked the question on the Umbraco forum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed or manually copied from another umbraco instance any 3rd party packages?

I found I had half copied the 301-url-tracker package that was then stopping nodes (that had never been published) from being deleted.

Although my error was for nodeid=0 I can not help but think the problem maybe the same.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/28216-Can-not-delete-a-content-tree-entity

Answer (score 0):

Work your way up the content tree and make sure each parent node is published and has a URL shown in the node properties.

I had a similar problem with the uDateFoldersy package and discovered the parent year folder was not published with a URL.  Once I had republished that, the child node began to work properly again.